# $state.go of Angular UI Router is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Nzno2xwDgC9fiItDFzfG?p=preview) link of the issue. I have configured 3 states : `signup`, `signin` & `todos`. I have configured `run` block too with `$stateChangeStart` event attached, to ensure i redirect to `signin` page if user is not logged in. In my project i use `AuthencationService` for the validation but i have commented that part to simplify the example.

Ideally, if my understanding is correct, `$stateChangeStart` will be called on every state change & it will be called when loading the application too. So no matter which state i hit i should be redirected to `signin` state, as i do not have any `AuthenticationService` checks here. I have written `console.log` to check it & its getting called.

```
console.log('User is not signed in !! Sign-in please.');
```

When the application loads (here when you load the plunker), `console.log` is getting printed

[image]

But the next statement `$state.go('signin' , {}, {notify: false});` is not taking view to `signin` page.

**WTF ?**

I have commented `event.preventDefault();` despite of knowing its use. If i use it then nothing gets loaded, not even **todos** page !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the notify, use `event.preventDefault()` and watch out for infinite loop

https://plnkr.co/edit/pHLyUwCXBG4KwWdmI3l8?p=preview

Edit: To elaborate on the infinite loop. You set up simple condition to check if user is logged in. If not, you want to redirect him to `signin` page. However, this check also fires for the `signin` state, so you get infinite loop of redirects. Just add simple `if` to check if `currentState` is the `signin` state, where you want to redirect.

`event.preventDefault()` is the correct way to stop state transition, so leave that one uncommented.

Comment: How do i watch out for infinite loop ? That was the reason for setting `notify:false`

Comment: thats the if I added to check if `toState.name` is `signin`. check the plunker

Answer (score 1):

`notify:false` prevents `$stateChangeStart` and `$stateChangeSuccess` from being fired so the transition will never complete since the UI only loads after the `$stateChangeSuccess` event is fired.

Check out [this Github issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1158) to see a way to do redirection within the `$stateChangeStart` eventListener. Basically, you have to manually broadcast the `$stateChangeStart` event after using `notify:false`. I'm using this method currently and it works really well. The caveat is that this is a really specific use case where I need to pause the transition momentarily to load data and build a new url. In most cases, `notify:false` is an anti-pattern that should be avoided. Make sure you have a good reason to use it and go through the rigamarole of working around it.

Comment: thanks for your answer man. Helped me in understanding the real use of `notify:false`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the inifinite loop you can use `$changeStateSuccess`, but in order to be fired you need to also change `notify` to `true` (you can read more [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#options/))

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    //If user is not signed in
        //if (!$rootScope.authentication.user) {
            console.log('User is not signed in !! Sign-in please.');
            // event.preventDefault();
            $state.go('signin' , {}, {notify: true});
         //}
});
```

Comment: Can you edit the plunker n check if your answer is working. It is not working for me !

Comment: Sure, here you go: https://plnkr.co/edit/FToFoDOcVGQsjSd6sE98?p=preview

Comment: If he uses `$changeStaetSuccess` the state will be already loaded, and that's something you wouldn't work. You don't want to load resources for not logged user, as well there might be data loaded for the specific logged user. These situations wouldnt work if the user is not logged in.